# Audit Trail in Oracle 11gR2

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, audit

I'm using Oracle 11g R2 on RHEL5.

How can I find what is being audited? I want to know what actions (like create, insert, delete, update etc.) are being audited or logged for a user, say `scott`.

Comment: Aren't they all listed in the manual?

Answer (score -1):

This topic is documented in the Oracle Security Guide at the section [Finding Information About Audited Activities](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/auditing.htm#DBSEG0635).

In your case you should find useful the catalog view `DBA_OBJ_AUDIT_OPTS` which displays the objects on which auditing options have been enabled.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_4153.htm#REFRN23141) is described the view structure.

Comment: -1 in my opinion oracle auditing views are rather confusing. so there should be more than some links to a manual. A concrete example of how one could find what is logged for user SCOTT would be useful, and will it be loged if the user SCOTT changes data in the tanble EMP?